# repeat occurrences with preg_match_all

Tags: php, loops, preg-match, repeat

I need to use `preg_match_all` to repeat occurrence within a given text. eg.
*input*: "Lorem Ipsum is simply **[repeat]** dummy **[/ repeat]** text of the printing and typesetting industry."
*output*: "Lorem Ipsum is simply **dummy dummy** text of the printing and typesetting industry."
examples have already tried but my limitations do not help.
I am grateful for who can help me, thanks

Comment: Please post the code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will also need to replace occurrences of [repeat].

Based on @Jerska answer:

```
$output = preg_replace ("#(\[repeat\])(.+)(\[/repeat\])#isU", '$2$2', $input);
```

Comment: You actually changed nothing to my answer except adding unneeded parenthesis. Those `[repeat]` will be stripped from the text with my answer. Finally, for this kind of changes, don't hesitate to click the "edit" link.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use preg_replace :

```
$output = preg_replace ("#\[repeat\](.+)\[/repeat\]#isU", "$1$1", $input);
```

and you're done. :)

Comment: Jerska, it would be almost, but I need separate occurrence because repetition is with loop.
Yan, I need a direction in order to create the function.

Comment: preg_replace replace all the occurences in the string if that's what you mean. It is already a loop.